# Automatically rename tabs

Tags: excel, vba

The script below loops through to create tabs and name the tab then it will place the tab name in cell B3. It's been working fine but now gives the catch all runtime error 1004.  At the bottom of my script it renames the tab.  This is where the error is happening.  It's creating the tabs but fails to rename it.  Can anyone please suggest another way to rename the tab in this script.   The error is on Sheets(Name).Select.

```
Public Sub CreateTabs()
  Sheets("TABlist").Select
  ' Determine how many Names are on Data sheet
  FinalRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
  ' Loop through each Name on the data sheet
  For x = 1 To FinalRow
    LastSheet = Sheets.Count
    Sheets("TABlist").Select
    Name = Range("A" & x).Value
    ' Make a copy of FocusAreas and move to end
    Sheets("TABshell").Copy After:=Sheets(LastSheet)
    ' rename the sheet and put name in Cell B2
    Sheets(LastSheet + 1).Name = Name
    Sheets(Name).Select
    Range("B3").Value = Name
  Next x 
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you make it a bit clearer to read. It looks like minimized jQuery to me and goes straight over my head!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got lost amid all the selects so I am not sure why your original code failed.  I edited your question to make it more readable but only I can see the improvement until my edit it peer reviewed.

I have deleted all your select statements.  Comments starting '## explain why I have made other changes.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CreateTabs()

   Dim CrntRow As Long              '## I like names I understand
   Dim FinalRow As Long
   Dim Name As String

   ' Determine how many Names are on Data sheet
   '## Row.Count will work for any version of Excel
   FinalRow = Sheets("TABlist").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   ' Loop through each Name on the data sheet
   For CrntRow = 1 To FinalRow
     Name = Sheets("TABlist").Range("A" & CrntRow).Value
     ' Make a copy of FocusAreas and move to end
     Sheets("TABshell").Copy After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
     ' rename the sheet and put name in Cell B2
     '## The copy will be the active sheet
     With ActiveSheet
       .Name = Name
       .Range("B3").Value = Name
     End With
   Next CrntRow

End Sub
```

Comment: This script generates a compile error at the =Sheets(LastSheet). I see how you changed the looping count but I am not sure how it should work to resolve the compile error.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how I missed that.  I must have made changes to the code after I tested it.  I have corrected my answer by replacing `LastSheet` with `Worksheets.Count`.  The revised code works on my system and I have just used it to create 4 new worksheets.

Comment: Thank you - I am very lucky you showed me this correction, becouse the answer above yours was working but now it's giving a compile error...  Your correction is a life saver..

Answer (score 5):

It is very important to write code that is robust. It shouldn't fail in any scenario. For example appropriate error handling should be done and variables declared.

I would recommend reading this.

***Topic***: To ‘Err’ is Human

***Link***: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/01/to-err-is-human/

Now back to your code. I have amended the code. Try this. I have also commented the code so you shouldn't have any difficulty understanding it :) Still if you do, just give a shout.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CreateTabs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FinalRow As Long, x As Long, LastSheet As Long
    Dim name As String

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ws = Sheets("TABlist")

    FinalRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 1 To FinalRow
        LastSheet = Sheets.Count

        '~~> Get the name for the new sheet
        name = ws.Range("A" & x).Value

        '~~> Check if you already have a sheet with that name or not
        If Not SheetExists(name) Then
            Sheets("TABshell").Copy After:=Sheets(LastSheet)
            ActiveSheet.name = name
            Range("B3").Value = name
        End If
    Next x

LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub

'~~> Function to check if sheet exists
Function SheetExists(wst As String) As Boolean
    Dim oSheet As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oSheet = Sheets(wst)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not oSheet Is Nothing Then SheetExists = True
End Function
```

Comment: I agree with robust coding and will read the link.  Your script is creating and naming the tabs with the name in the cell.  I beleive you have solved it..  I'm not sure why my original script worked for a long time and off and on still does.  But hopefully you making it more robust - it will not also fail later.  VERY MUCH appreciate the help....

Comment: user745778, you unaccepted my solution. Could you confirm where did it fail if it did?

Answer (score 1):

Each worksheet name in an Excel workbook needs to be unique.

As a quick fix to see what name is causing the error, try using this code and then check the sheet names against your list.

```
Public Sub CreateTabs()

On Error Resume Next

  Sheets("TABlist").Select
  ' Determine how many Names are on Data sheet
  FinalRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
  ' Loop through each Name on the data sheet
  For x = 1 To FinalRow
    LastSheet = Sheets.Count
    Sheets("TABlist").Select
    Name = Range("A" & x).Value
    ' Make a copy of FocusAreas and move to end
    Sheets("TABshell").Copy After:=Sheets(LastSheet)
    ' rename the sheet and put name in Cell B2
    Sheets(LastSheet + 1).Name = Name
    Sheets(Name).Select
    Range("B3").Value = Name
  Next x

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: I reduced my list to Two. your script creates three as expected first one being called "name". How do you think this will identify the problem record?  When I remove your On Error, the original error occurs with only these two records.

Comment: Check to see if you have any hidden sheets.  This will cause issues with the Sheets.Count and possibly setting the sheet name.